# Screen rotation breaks widget Android

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

When I rotate the screen on a tablet, my widget's list view disappears and the buttons become unclickable. I'm not sure what happening with the most recent remote view to cause this. Any suggestions?

Here is my onUpdate function

[onUpdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKeqk.png)

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Shared onUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have the full code, it's kind of hard to give an actual answer to your problem.

However, I might have an idea & the cause of your problem could be in your .XML file. The same way your app looks great in a certain rotation, most surely on the one you originally designed your work on, it is very possible that it might result in problems when you changed the rotation.

However, it all depends of the layouts you are using & how they are used. I would advise to share your entire code so we can go through it.